# What liability do hospitals have for timely care, if they think you're faking it?

Tags: medical, australia, malpractice

A while ago my girlfriend was admitted to hospital. She had intense 10/10 pain from one of her ovaries, and ended up having to have it removed.
Unfortunately, she was made to wait for around 6 hours at the first hospital while one of the doctors sneered at her and made comments including 'Well you're playing it up, aren't you?'

After 4-5 hours of nothing, she was inspected thoroughly and then transferred, put into surgery and made a full recovery.
An OBGYN later told my girlfriend that they would have saved her ovary if they acted immediately after looking at the photos and a long talk about it.

What Australian law could possibly have been breached here? Is this abuse or fully legal as withstanding discretion from a doctor to "make sure you're not faking it" may apply? Applying blame and intentional malice hinges on it, I think.